# C++ thread issue with data copy

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying a simple thread program on using gcc HEAD 7.0.0 20161020 and c+1z(GNU)

Very simple program,

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Task
{
    public:
    Task(int i):_i(i){}
    Task(const Task& p):_i(p._i){std::cout<<"Copy called:"<<_i<<std::endl;}
    void operator()(){std::cout<<"operator()"<<_i<<std::endl;}
    void runTask(void* p)
    {
        if (p) {}
        std::cout<<"runTask():"<<_i<<std::endl;
    }
    private:
    int _i;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Begin main()"<<std::endl;
    Task tsk1(11);
    Task tsk2(22);    
    Task tsk3(33);    
    std::cout<<"Create threads"<<std::endl;
    std::thread t1 {tsk1};
    std::thread t2(&Task::runTask, &tsk2, nullptr);
    std::thread t3(&Task::runTask, &tsk3, nullptr);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    std::cout<<"End main()"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives output as:-

```
Begin main()
Create threads
Copy called:11
Copy called:11
operator()11
runTask():22
runTask():33
End main()
0
```

Can anyone suggest why the copy constructor for thread t1 gets called twice and not once as expected ? Also, why there is no copy constructor called for threads t2 and t3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first "task" is copied once when you pass it into the `std::thread` constructor, and copied again when it's sent to the actual worker thread.

Neither of your other tasks are ever copied anywhere — all you do there is copy pointers-to-tasks.

Comment: Ohkk, however, I think that there should be just one copy of data of thread 1, not 2nd time when it is passed to actual thread,

Comment: @cpp11dev: Why do you think that? Which passage in the standard/documentation or which code in the compiler's source, has led you to this conclusion?

Comment: For thread t1:

Thread constructors from the latest C++ n4606 standard say


template <class F, class ...Args> explicit thread(F&& f, Args&&... args);

thread(thread&&) noexcept;

Comment: @cpp11dev: Starting up a `std::thread` involves a lot more than just passing an argument to the `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: So do you suggest that because of thread constructors having && , thread 1 and thread t2, t3 exhibit the above behavior ? I mean for thread t1, once copy is genuine as its copy by value, but for thread t2 and t3, because of && there is no copy involved. Or will it show same behavior if constructor was just &

Comment: Also, as you mentioned, 2nd copy of thread t1 is because it is passed to the actual execution function, but in that case it is just a functor which takes no arguments then howcome the 2nd copy still ? Also, how can I avoid the 2nd copy if I want to

Comment: @cpp11dev: Give your type a move constructor.